# An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  @Model ElectsWatch.Models.Products

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>AdminEdit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> 

            <h2>Продукт № @Model.Id</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AdminEdit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <fieldset>
           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Название продукта")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, "Описание")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description)

        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, "Цена")
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Price)
        </p>

    </fieldset>
    }
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

в самой первой строке измение `@Model` на `@model`

оператор `@model` объявляет тип объекта модели, а через `@Model` производится доступ к объекту модели.